# Unrolling procedural code into SQL

Tags: sql, procedural-programming, ansi-sql, turing-complete

The act of transforming procedural code into SQL has been of interest to me lately. I know that not absolutely everything is expressable in a turing complete procedural language.

What if you have a special purpose procedural language though? For instance converting something like this:

```
foreach(var row in Table){
  if(row.FirstName=="Foo"){
    yield new {row.TableRID};
  }
}
```

into this:

```
select TableRID from Table where FirstName='Foo'
```

Is there a name for something like this?

Also, in my psuedo code assume that `row` is immutable and it is impossible to do something like `Table[0].FirstName...` and other things which obviously have no (easy) translation into ANSI SQL.

Can anyone give me a name for this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is expressible in a Turing-complete procedural language. It's not always expressive, though. Sometimes you can gain expressiveness by removing power, creating a *domain-specific language*, or *DSL*, for the kind of problem you want to solve. Maybe this is the term you are looking for?

SQL without extensions is not Turing-complete, so as you note, only a subset of the possible programs of a Turing-complete language can be transformed.

Comment: Wikipedia says ANSI SQL is turing complete though? I fail to see how though

Comment: Where?

[WP:Transact-SQL](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Transact-SQL)

"Transact-SQL augments SQL with certain additional features . . . These additional features make Transact-SQL Turing complete."

Comment: nevermind it got edited out: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=SQL&action=historysubmit&diff=376242269&oldid=376220546